# Use of large motor capacitors to stop voltage drops from because of high electrical draws

Tags: voltage

Good Day Everyone. 
Please bear with me and have patience. I have a feeling I will quickly be considered the village idiot here. 
I have trouble with voltage fluctuation especially with high demand draws such as air compressors and welders. What I want to do is wire large motor starting capacitors in line to eliminate this. I did find a little information about this but they seemed to have a pretty sketchy grasp on this. 
I'm working with single phase 220 volt any information would be appreciated.

Comment: You seem to have a misconception. A "capacitor" will not help you with an AC supply to AC loads. Actual solutions to this problem are neither simple nor inexpensive. Your best bet is simply to upgrade your wiring to reduce losses, but if the drop is at your utility pole this will not help.

Comment: It is lousy power on average it runs about 114-116 volts. I'm in a rural location and at the end of the line. I own a crushing and screening operation and I run everything there is on three phase 480. Its insanely bad I took an old welder I have that can run single or three phase out of the shop to the pit. Everything is more efficient on three phase but it runs incredibly well now. I had intended on just using it for air arcing until the magic smoke escaped but not any more.

Comment: Can you update the question with some more specific details on what are you trying to accomplish, how is power sag affecting you, what is the estimated consumption/duration? 114V is within range for distribution voltage even in urban areas (going all the way down to 104 within the premises under load)

Comment: Hi Edgar I'm trying to get the lights to quit flickering when hi draws like the air compressor is running or a welding is going on.

Comment: approximately how many lights/watts total? What type? Are these in a separate circuit?

Comment: Hi Edgar. Oh yes it is on a separate circuit and they are now nearly all LED.. The lights will flicker in the house also while compressor is running. I once caused a bit of a brownout all the way back to town air arcing on a rock crusher.One of the power company guys showed up at the shop looking for the short in the power companies system. I haven't measured what the voltage is under load but its low.

Comment: Non-dimmable LEDs? Because those tend to have an extremely wide regulation range. How much total power in the lights?  500W 1000W?

Answer (score 2):

I am not surprised that something you found on the internet about that is pretty sketchy. That will generally not work for an AC motor. Single-phase capacitor-start and capacitor-run capacitors are sized to be suitable for the motor design. The value can not be changed very much without having a negative effect on motor performance and/or damaging the motor.

If the root of the problem is an overloaded service transformer or perhaps even an overloaded branch circuit, it might help to connect power-factor compensation capacitors. Power-factor compensation capacitors connected near the motor loads would supply the reactive component of the motor current locally rather than drawing it from the source. That would reduce the current drawn from the source thereby reducing the voltage drop in the impedance of the service transformer and distribution wiring. You can not use motor-starting capacitors for that purpose because they are designed for short-time use only during starting and must be automatically disconnected by a device that senses the motor is approaching operating speed.

Motors with capacitors for starting or running may not benefit very much from power-factor compensation capacitors. Adding too much capacitance can cause over-voltage problems. It would be best to measure the power factor before adding power factor capacitors.

The problem may be distribution system wire that is sized adequately for the current, but not for the distance between the service entrance and the loads. You may need to install separate, and larger branch circuit wiring for the largest motors.

Comment: Ok I think I was using the wrong search words. I seen a system at another operation  that had a series of large capacitors at the main distribution panel for the same problem some time ago and didn't have the foresight to examine it more closely. All my wiring is sized one size above as is the magnetic switches that I use for high demand loads like air compressors. I prefer to use buss type fuses rather than circuit breakers. Time delay fuses especially give a better power than a breaker can. Hey I told you guys up front. You left the door open and the mongol hordes got in.